# Update one by one records using loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Sector ID, need to update sector name and sector short name as 'Sector 1' and 'Sector 1' for each sector id respectively using loop. How can I achieve this?

```
SectorID    SectorName  SectorShortName
---------------------------------------
1   METALS  METAL
2   FINANCIAL SERVICES  FINAN
3   IT  IT
4   SERVICES    SERVI
5   PHARMA  PHARM
6   CHEMICALS   CHEMI
7   TEXTILES    TEXTI
8   ENERGY  ENERG
9   INDUSTRIAL MANUFACTURING    INDUS
10  CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS    CEMEN
11  CONSUMER GOODS  CONSU
12  CONSTRUCTION    CONST
13  TELECOM TELEC
14  AUTOMOBILE  AUTOM
15  HEALTHCARE SERVICES HEALT
16  FERTILISERS & PESTICIDES    FERTI
17  MEDIA & ENTERTAINMENT   MEDIA
18  PAPER   PAPER
19  PENDING UPDATION    PENDING
20  OTHERS  OTHERS
21  FINANCIAL SERVICES - HFC (AA and Above) FS-HFC-AA
22  Scheduled Commercial Bank   SCB
23  FINANCIAL SERVICES - PSU, PFI (AAA)     PSUPFIAAA
24  NO  NO
25  YES YES
26  FINANCIAL SERVICES - HFC (Below AA) FSHFC<AA
27  Other than PSU, PFI & PSB   Limit Appl
28  PSU PSU
29  PSB PSB
30  PFI PFI
31  SOVEREIGN   SOVEREIGN
```

Comment: Why you want to go with `loop` ? However, this could be easily achieve via single `update`  statement.

Comment: because i have other database too which have same table structure, if i have to update then it will be only run one time, while using loop it will be in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply use `update`:

```
update sectors
    set SectorName = replace('sector [n]', '[n]', id),
        SectorShortName = replace('sector [n]', '[n]', id);
```

There is absolutely no reason to be using a loop for this.  Or more specifically, `update` covers all the rows in the table using set-based operations, so it is more efficient and the code is shorter.