# Update records one by one using loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

My SQL table is Like below

```
**name  department  fee_paid    id**
----------------------------------------
Ajay    ECE          10000     1
Ranjit  EEE          20000     2
----------------------------------------
```

now i wish to fill data like below

```
**name  department  fee_paid    id**
----------------------------------------
Name1    Name1       10000     1
Name2    Name2       20000     2
----------------------------------------
```

Need to update this with while loop

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952675/update-one-by-one-records-using-loop-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to go with `loop` ?

This could also be simplify via `update`

```
update table 
set name = concat('name', id),
    department  = concat('name', id);
```

**EDIT** (by gordon):

The more general solution for SQL Server is:

```
update table 
set name = 'name' + cast(id as varchar(255)),
    department  = 'name' + cast(id as varchar(255));
```

`CONCAT()` was not introduced until SQL Server 2012 and the question does explicitly include SQL Server 2008 as a tag.